# How can I use a pretrained Keras model in pytorch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I have a .h5 model file which I'd like to fine-tune, but doing it in Pytorch would make my life a lot easier. So is it possible to convert a keras model to pytorch (the architecture and then copying weights) and if so, is there a straightforward way of doing it?

I was on my way to building the architecture in Pytorch (I'm not exactly a pro so it's taking a bit), but then wasn't sure if it would even make sense, once I had the architecture, to copy-paste the weights from one framework to another?
Any help is appreciated!